# Как правильно организовать частое общение клиентов с сервером?

Tags: c#, сервер

У меня есть сервер, я его написал на C#, и клиенты, они отправляют разного рода сообщения по TCP/IP. Ну вот мне нужно кое что придумать или подсказать как правильно это можно реализовать. Нужно, чтобы запрос отправлялся с сервера к клиенту, знаю что такое нельзя сделать, причина в том что, каждую секунду или 10 секунд, не комильфо теребонкать сервер, учитывать, то что пользователей может доходить до 20-30 одновременно. Можно ли найти какую нибудь альтернативу.

Comment: Протокол TCP позволяет отправлять данные в обе стороны.

Comment: Значит клиенты должны ждать подключения, а не отправлять запросы? А сервер по очереди их опрашивать? Или сервер в режиме ожидания ждёт подключения, но в какой то момент начинает сам опрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком мало конкретики в вопросе, но если не предпринимать это в расчет для реализации механизма уведомления сервером клиента на ум приходят следующие варианты:

1. Wcf [дуплексные службы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx)  это ситуация при которой и клиент и сервер одновременно является и `Service Consumer` и `Service Provider`, т.е. если говорить простыми словами у сервера появляется возможность вызывать методы на стороне клиента.
2. Использование очередей, например того же `RabbitMq` (режим `Publish/Subscribe`, по факту этот режим это реализация паттерна [издатель-подписчик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))), суть заключается в том, что клиент подписывается на определенную информацию (событие). Что это может быть? Да все что угодно, например, нас могут интересовать какие-то исключения, которые происходят при работе серверной стороны приложения. В этом случае, при возникновении исключения мы (сервер) осуществляем `Publish` и уведомляем всех подписавшихся на это событие клиентов о его возникновении.

Добавлю, что все эти механизмы работают из коробки, т.е. мудрить и придумывать какие-то костыли и велосипеды не надо ) Так что смотрите, возможно что-то из предложенного подойдет и Вам.